How do I interpret this picture of a spectrahedron?
On the Wikipedia page on spectrahedron, it shows the following picture of a spectrahedron (I avoid using the term image since it seems to have special meaning in this context)

I understand everything on the wikipedia page and have a rudimentary understanding of positive semidefinite matrices and semidefinite programming.
But nothing seems to connect to this particular picture of a spectrahedron.  Is this a 3D projection (image) of some hypothetical p.s.d. matrix?  What do the x, y, z axes represent?  Why does it look like a bloated, rounded tetrahedron?

If you search on MSE with the  keyword "spectrahedron" or "spectrahedra" (in "Search on Mathematics"), you will get more than 60 "hits", some of them connected to your question.  See also this document connecting spectrahedra and super-ellipsoids.
